# Use different database for the npm test phase

Tags: node.js, heroku, mocha.js

Environment: heroku, node.js - express, testing with mocha.

How can I configure heroku to launch the `npm test` with NODE_ENV="test" and invoke the server ("`node server.js`") with NODE_ENV="production" .

This means that I need two server invocations - once for testing (where I connect to my test db) and once for production (where I connect to my production db)

I want to use different db in the "`npm test`" phase since my tests also create fake data.

Here is how my test look like:

```
var supertest = require("supertest");
var should = require('chai').should();
var config = require('../server/config');

var server = supertest.agent(config.baseUrl);

describe("User controller", function () {
    describe("HTTP Verbs", function () {
         it("GET", function (done) {
              console.log(config.dbUrl);
              console.log(config.baseUrl);
              server.post("/api/user") {
                  .send(utils.createMockedUserPlainObject())
                  .end(function(err, res) {

                  server.get("/api/user/list")
                    .expect("Content-type", /json/)
                    .expect(200) // THis is HTTP response
                    .end(function (err, res) {
                        // HTTP status should be 200
                        res.status.should.equal(200);
                        res.body.should.have.length(1);

                        done();
                  });
              })
          });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

Its seems the magic lies inside supertest.

replace:

```
var server = supertest.agent(config.baseUrl);
```

with:

```
var app = require('../server');

var server = supertest.agent(app);
```